# How do I prevent Xamarin Forms apps from breaking, when I switch between different projects/apps?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have multiple Xamarin Forms projects for different apps.

Sometimes when I switch between the projects or create a new one, every single app shows one of various error messages, preventing it from starting.
Usually I "fix" this, by deleting the broken project and restarting my computer, however this time it still doesn´t work. The error messages keep showing up, even my main project (which usually works fine) is bugged now.

Is there some sort of cache or some process that I can delete? Does someone know any other way of fixing this without deleting projects?

Each project seems to have different issues, here are 3 of the error messages that appear. I didn´t copy the other ones when I had the chance.

First:

```
Fehler      Fehler beim Generieren des Java-Typs für die Klasse "AndroidX.Core.View.Accessibiity.AccessibilityManagerCompat/IAccessibilityStateChangeListenerImplementor" aufgrund von MAX_PATH: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Ein Teil des Pfades "C:\Users\trygve.defreese\source\repos\Eigen\Vorlagen\Mehrsprachigkeit mit I18n\LanguageSupportI18n\LanguageSupportI18n.Android\obj\Debug\110\android\src\mono\androidx\core\view\accessibility\AccessibilityManagerCompat_AccessibilityStateChangeListenerImplementor.java" konnte nicht gefunden werden.
   bei System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   bei System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   bei System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize)
   bei Microsoft.Android.Build.Tasks.Files.CopyIfStreamChanged(Stream stream, String destination) in /Users/builder/azdo/_work/2/s/xamarin-android/external/xamarin-android-tools/src/Microsoft.Android.Build.BaseTasks/Files.cs:Zeile 170.
   bei Xamarin.Android.Tasks.GenerateJavaStubs.CreateJavaSources(IEnumerable`1 javaTypes, TypeDefinitionCache cache).   LanguageSupportI18n.Android
```

Second:

```
Fehler  MSB4018 Unerwarteter Fehler bei der XamlCTask-Aufgabe.
System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: Die Assembly "Mono.Cecil, Version=0.10.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=50cebf1cceb9d05e" kann nicht gefunden werden.

Server stack trace: 
   bei System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryAssemblyInfo.GetAssembly()
   bei System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.GetType(BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, String name)
   bei System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectMap..ctor(String objectName, String[] memberNames, BinaryTypeEnum[] binaryTypeEnumA, Object[] typeInformationA, Int32[] memberAssemIds, ObjectReader objectReader, Int32 objectId, BinaryAssemblyInfo assemblyInfo, SizedArray assemIdToAssemblyTable)
   bei System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMapTyped(BinaryObjectWithMapTyped record)
   bei System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.ReadObjectWithMapTyped(BinaryHeaderEnum binaryHeaderEnum)
   bei System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.__BinaryParser.Run()
   bei System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectReader.Deserialize(HeaderHandler handler, __BinaryParser serParser, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   bei System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Deserialize(Stream serializationStream, HeaderHandler handler, Boolean fCheck, Boolean isCrossAppDomain, IMethodCallMessage methodCallMessage)
   bei System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSerializer.DeserializeObject(MemoryStream stm)
   bei System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.SmuggledMethodReturnMessage.FixupForNewAppDomain()
   bei System.Runtime.Remoting.Channels.CrossAppDomainSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage reqMsg)

Exception rethrown at [0]: 
   bei System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   bei System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   bei Microsoft.Build.Framework.ITask.Execute()
   bei Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskExecutionHost.Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.ITaskExecutionHost.Execute()
   bei Microsoft.Build.BackEnd.TaskBuilder.<ExecuteInstantiatedTask>d__26.MoveNext()    BDE_App C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Xamarin\NuGet\xamarin.forms\5.0.0.2012\buildTransitive\Xamarin.Forms.targets   119
```

Third(this one appeared 15 times at once):

```
Schweregrad Code    Beschreibung    Projekt Datei   Zeile   Unterdrückungszustand
Fehler      failed to open directory: Das System kann die angegebene Datei nicht finden. (2).   Testprojekt5.Android    C:\Users\trygve.defreese\source\repos\Eigen\Übungen\Testprojekt5\Testprojekt5.Android\obj\Debug\110\lp\51\jl\res
```

Edit:
Steps to reproduce the issue:
Open a Xamarin Forms project
Load project to mobile device
Open a second Xamarin Forms project, leaving the first one open
Load second project to mobile device

This usually provokes the issue, I cannot guarantee it though.

Comment: You can try to delete the bin folders and the obj folders and rebuild it . If it doesn’t work  ,try to restart the VS

Comment: Thanks, I deleted the broken project again but I will try it out the next time it breaks and update whether it worked or not. To be clear, you mean the bin and obj folders in the main folder and in the .Android folder of the project right?

Comment: Yes. you can try it.

Comment: Unfortunately this didn´t fix the problem.

Comment: I couldn't reproduce this problem on my side. Could you please post  the steps so that we can try to reproduce this problem on my side?

Comment: @JessieZhang-MSFT Sure, its in the edit.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot reproduce this problem by following your steps.